# Reaction rule raises TypeError

Tags: rules, debugging

I have a working Drupal 8.3.7 installation and use the `rules3.0alpha` module.

I add a reaction rule that is applied `After saving new comment`.

That's all.

Now, when I try to save a comment, I get an error:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\rules\Plugin\Condition\EntityHasField::doEvaluate() must implement interface Drupal\Core\Entity\FieldableEntityInterface, string given in Drupal\rules\Plugin\Condition\EntityHasField->doEvaluate()
```

What's wrong?